# Add Remote Site Setting via API

Tags: metadata-api, php, remote-site-settings

I am trying to add a new Remote Site Setting via API. I am using core PHP. After I run the following code I am getting this error.

```
$response = [
   0 => {
   "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND"
   "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
  }
]
```

It seems I am using wrong end point.
Can anyone guide me what are the end points for add new remote site?

OR

if I can't use rest api then what will be the soap envelope and soap end URL

Please Help.

Here is my code.

```
$url = $instance_url . '/services/data/v53.0/metadata/RemoteSiteSetting'; 
//RemoteProxy, RemoteSiteSetting
    $data = [
        'fullName'  => 'My First Hook', 
        'isActive'  =>  true,
        'url' => 'http://www.myServerUrl.com',
        'description' => 'Used for Apex callout to mapping web service for my server'
    ];
$result = $this->callAPI('POST', $url, $data, $access_token, ['accountId' => $accountId]);


public function callAPI($method = 'GET', $url = '', $data = [], $access_token = '', $extras = []) {
    $header = [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
        'X-PrettyPrint:1',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];
   

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    switch ($method) {
        case "GET":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
            break;
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            break;
        case "PATCH":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            break;
    }
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response_object = json_decode($response);
    return $response_object;
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to use [Named Credentials for callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)...even if there are no credentials managed by/stored in NC. Doing so automatically whitelists the target URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and posting here. Maybe someone need this.
Here is my php code.

```
$data = [
        'fullName'  => 'HookName',
        'isActive'  =>  true,
        'url' => 'https://www.mysite.com',
        'description' => 'Used for Apex callout to mapping web service for my server'
    ];
    $access_token = $tokens['access_token'];
    $url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo';
    $loginUserInfo = $this->callAPI('GET', $url , [], $tokens['access_token'], ['accountId' => $accountId]);
    $post_organization_id = '';
    if($loginUserInfo) {
       
        $organization_id = $loginUserInfo->organization_id;
        $post_organization_id = substr($organization_id, 0, -3);
    }
    
    
    $wsdl = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    $wsdl .=        '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    $wsdl .=            '<env:Header>';
    $wsdl .=                '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
    $wsdl .=                    '<urn:sessionId>' . $access_token . '</urn:sessionId>';
    $wsdl .=                '</urn:SessionHeader>';
    $wsdl .=            '</env:Header>';
    $wsdl .=            '<env:Body>';
    $wsdl .=                '<createMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
    $wsdl .=                    '<metadata xsi:type="RemoteSiteSetting">';
    $wsdl .=                        '<fullName>' . $data['fullName'] . '</fullName>';
    $wsdl .=                        '<description>'.$data['description'].'</description>';
    $wsdl .=                        '<disableProtocolSecurity>false</disableProtocolSecurity>';
    $wsdl .=                        '<isActive>true</isActive>';
    $wsdl .=                        '<url>' . $data['url'] . '</url>';
    $wsdl .=                    '</metadata>';
    $wsdl .=                '</createMetadata>';
    $wsdl .=            '</env:Body>';
    $wsdl .=        '</env:Envelope>';
    

    $xml_post_string = $wsdl;

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: RemoteSiteSetting",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
    );

    $url =  'https://yourSubDomain.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/49.0/'.$post_organization_id;

    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```